# WPF GridView Style bindings not updating on all columns

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf application, I have a grid view set up with an item style applied to all columns. One of the properties being bound is the foreground color of the TextBlock in each cell. I've wrapped the color in a simple object so that when the color is changed, it notifies past items in the list to also update.

However, When I change the color, not all of the list items are updating properly. The binding is working, but certain cells keep their old color. If I scroll down the list and back up, then all of the cells will correctly update. It seems this might be an issue with list virtualization. It also seems like it may be a bug, as only certain columns are not updating in the same row.

What can I do to work around this problem?

```
<ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="No." Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MessageListItemStyle}"
                                                               Text="{Binding Id}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
...
```

Color class:

```
public class Color : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Brush _brush;

    public Color(Brush brush)
    {
        _brush = brush;
    }

    public Brush Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _brush;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_brush, value))
            {
                _brush = value;
                var changed = PropertyChanged;
                if (changed != null)
                    changed(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MessageListItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ForeColor.Value}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: try setting virtualization off by setting following property <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Standard"/>

Comment: Strangely, this did not seem to fix the problem. In either case, I would like to keep the virtualization if possible.

Answer (score 0):

A bit long for a comment, how are you setting your `Color` on your objects? I was able to replicate the error you describe after making a slight mistake whilst making a small mockup.

I bound a `ListView` as you did above, and created a collection of 100 objects with a `Foreground` property, initialised to a new `SolidColorBrush`. All the objects were set to the initial colour without issue.

I then iterated through the collection to change the `Color` to something new using a line like this:

```
p.ForeColor = new Color(new SolidColorBrush(...));
```

So this was my mistake, because I'm setting a new `Color` every time, the setter on the `ForeColor` property is never firing, so no `PropertyChanged` event is fired. Only the items not currently in view are updated, the others remain the same until I scroll them all the way out of view.

What I should have done:

```
p.ForeColor.Value = new SolidColorBrush(...);
```

Then all the setters are hit, the events are fired, and everything works as I'd expect.

That may not be what's happening for you though.

Comment: Afraid not. I am correctly utilizing the property changed event.

Comment: D'oh, worth a shot. Can you post the code which populates your List, and changes the colour?